# How to overload a class

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8

Initially, I had a `Plan` class which behaves like this:

```
class Plan {
     public enum Type {
         FOO
     }

     String checkFoo() {
        // some check for foo
     } 

     String doSomething() {
     }
}
```

Now, I need to add another type called `Bar`.

```
class Plan {
     public enum Type {
         FOO, BAR
     }

     String checkFoo() {
        // some check for foo
     } 

     String checkBar() {
       // some check for bar
     }   

      String doSomething() {
     }
}
```

Now, checkFoo only works for Foo but does not work for Bar and vice-versa.
How is the best 'design pattern' to structure this ?  Should we add checks in each method and throw exceptions ? Is there a common solutions ?

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work`? Where is the overloading happening? Your example class doesn't extend anything.

Comment: but your question name though... a *method* is overloaded, not a class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "common solution" here is *polymorphism*.

In Java an *enum* is (almost) an ordinary class. Therfore it constants can implement *interfaces* like this:

```
interface Checkable{
  String doCheck();
}

class Plan {
     public enum Type implements Checkable{
         FOO{
            @Overide public String doheCheck() {
               return "result of Foo check";
            }
         }, BAR{
            @Overide public String doheCheck() {
               return "result of Bar check";
            }
         };
     }

     String check() {
          for(Checkable checkable: Type.values()){
              checkable.doCheck();
     } 


      String doSomething() {
     }
}
```

In any way your callers should not have to deal with the fact that there are different `Type`s to check...

Answer (score 3):

If I understood this correctly you could create your enum a bit different:

```
enum Type {

    FOO {
        public  String getMe(){
            return "FOO";
        }    
    };

    // force every instance to implement this
    public abstract String getMe();
}
```